# Spring Boot JPA, data do not persist in join table of many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many, one-to-many, many-to-one

I need some help/advice since I am new to Spring Boot. I am trying to make many-to-many relationship with the help of linking table. But for some reason, I can not persist data in the link table.

Here are the entities:

```
@Table(name = "providers")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class ProviderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long providerId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProviderPractitionersEntity> providerPractitioners; 

    ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_practitioner_types")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class CompanyPractitionerTypeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "practitioner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProviderPractitionersEntity> practitionerProviders;

    ...
}
---------------------------------------------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name = "provider_practitioners")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProviderPractitionersEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "practitioner_id") /*this column is foreign key from practitioner table*/
    private CompanyPractitionerEntity practitioner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id") /*this column is foreign key from provider table*/
    private ProviderEntity provider;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private String size;

}
```

When I am persisting new Provider, I set this new provider object's reference and practitioner object's reference in every ProviderPractitioner object before persisting.

As the result, objects from List providerPractitioners have null values for all states. And nothing is persisted to provider_practitioners table in the database.

The reason I am trying to set many-to-many relationship this way, instead of using @ManyToMany annotation is because of the "size" variable in ProviderPractitionerEntity which contains number of one type of practitioners for one provider.

I have tried to create embededId (composite ID) for linking table, and got the same result.

********* UPDATE ***********

I created embededId class as suggested:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

public class ProviderPractitionersId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "practitioner_id")
    private Long practitionerId;

    @Column(name = "provider_id")
    private Long providerId;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ProviderPractitionersId)) return false;
        ProviderPractitionersId that = (ProviderPractitionersId) o;
        return Objects.equals(getPractitionerId(), that.getPractitionerId()) && Objects.equals(getProviderId(), that.getProviderId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getPractitionerId(), getProviderId());
    }
}
```

and added it to the join Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "provider_practitioners")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProviderPractitionersEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProviderPractitionersId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("practitionerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "practitioner_id")
    private CompanyPractitionerEntity practitioner;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("providerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
    private ProviderEntity provider;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private String size;

}
```

This is my join table in DB

```
create table provider_practitioners
(
    practitioner_id integer,
    provider_id     integer,
    size            varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (practitioner_id, provider_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (practitioner_id) REFERENCES company_practitioners (id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES providers (provider_id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I am setting values to each ProviderPractitionersEntity (Id, provider reference, practitioner reference, size value) Before, I did not set the ID object.

```
public Set<ProviderPractitionersEntity> dtoToPractitionersEntity(final ProviderDto providerDto,
                                                                     final ProviderEntity providerEntity) {
        final Set<ProviderPractitionersEntity> providerPractitionersEntities = new HashSet<>();

        //Iterate through passed list of practitioner types for given provider
        providerDto.getPractitioners().forEach(practitionerDTO -> {

            final ProviderPractitionersEntity providerPractitioner = new ProviderPractitionersEntity();

            //Check if there is current practitioner type in the codebook table with practitioner types
            final CompanyPractitionerEntity practitioner = companyPractitionerRepository.findByPractitionerId(practitionerDTO).orElseThrow();

            //add provider-practitioner set's reference to practitioner object
            practitioner.setPractitionerProviders(providerPractitionersEntities);

            //add current practitioner reference to ProviderPractitioner instance
            providerPractitioner.setPractitioner(practitioner);

            //add provider reference to ProviderPractitioner entity instance
            providerPractitioner.setProvider(providerEntity);

            //add values to the key and add key to the ProviderPractitioner instance
            final ProviderPractitionersId providerPractitionersId = new ProviderPractitionersId(practitioner.getId(), providerEntity.getProviderId());
            providerPractitioner.setId(providerPractitionersId);
    //set size
    providerPractitioner.setSize("5-10");
```

When I try to persist Provider object, now I get javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find providers.model.entity.ProviderPractitionersEntity with id ProviderPractitionersId(practitionerId=2, providerId=0).

providerId is 0 at this point because provider object is not persisted yet. Why is it trying to fetch it? Is it because I set up the key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `@EmbeddedId` as you mentioned, and then in the `ProviderPractitionersEntity` attributes (`ProviderEntity` and `CompanyPractitionerTypeEntity`) add `@MapsId` with the name of the property in the composite id.

So first create the composite id:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProviderPractitionersId implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "practitioner_id")
   private Long practitionerId;

   @Column(name = "provider_id")
   private Long providerId;
```

And then, in the many-to-many entity (`ProviderPractitionersEntity`) map the id and both entities this way:

```
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProviderPractitionersId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("practitionerId")
    private CompanyPractitionerTypeEntity practitioner;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("providerId")
    private ProviderEntity provider;
```

And so, in the `ProviderPractitionersEntity` you can add, as you mentioned, as many properties as you like, like your `size` or anything else.

**Update** after comments

As you said, relations are automatically persisted or not depending on the `CascadeType` you specify. If none is specified you have to manually persist all entities (including the middle table) and at the correct order. First the Provider and the Practitioner have to exist in their tables in order for the ProviderPractitioner to get inserted, as this has foreign keys to those tables. So you either fine tune the `CascadeType` at your needs, or perform all the inserts manually in the correct order. That depends on your specific business cases.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply gmanjon. I tried with EmbededId and done everything as you suggested. I overrided equals and hashcode in ProviderPractitionersId class as well. Just like before, as the result I get list of objects, but all states are still null.

Comment: Ok. Could you please detail in your question what is exactly the outcome? Which properties are null, and after doin which query, the database table columns and which values are filled and which ones aren't. And the most important, although as you didn't say probably there is none, any Exceptions in the log? Thanks!

Comment: And what you mean with "all states"? The r st of the entities work well?

Comment: "_When I am persisting new Provider, I set this new provider object's reference and practitioner object's reference in every ProviderPractitioner object before persisting._" <- Is better to provide the sample code instead of explaining it :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me ones again @gmanjon. I posted the update to my post. I did not instantiate embededId class before. Now when I do and pass the ID values, I get exception as I posted in the update.

Comment: I got it! cascadeType on providerPractitioners field in ProvaderEntity sould be **all** 

Now everything works

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProviderPractitionersEntity> providerPractitioners;

Comment: Great! Happy to help. I updated the answer with an explanation about the cascade types for if it can help others that end up here.